# Copying files from one PC To another without sharing the destination folder with everyone in C#

Tags: c#, copy, impersonation

I want to transfer a folder with data from one PC to another .However the destination PC is not shared with everyone .A specific user has been given read/write access to it .I tried impersonation of the user and tried to transfer ,however i get the error "network name not found" .If i share the folder with everyone i am able to copy the folder data from source to destination.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace VMS3.Admin.Forms_Deployment
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for fDeploy.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class fDeploy : Page
    {
        public fDeploy()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            string sourcePath = txtFileupload.Text;
            string targetPath = "\\\\server name\\Application\\VMS3";
            


            if (ImpersonateUser("BRANCHOFFICE", "Username", "Password") == true)
            {
                
                CopyFilesRecursively(sourcePath, targetPath);

                undoImpersonation();
            }
            else
            {
                //Could not authenticate account. Something is up.
                //Log or something.
            }

        }

        #region Impersionation global variables
        public const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
        public const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;

        WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext;

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
        public static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName,
            String lpszDomain,
            String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType,
            int dwLogonProvider,
            ref IntPtr phToken);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken,
            int impersonationLevel,
            ref IntPtr hNewToken);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool RevertToSelf();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
        #endregion

        private bool ImpersonateUser(string domain, string userName, string password)
        {
            WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
            IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
            IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (RevertToSelf())
            {
                if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                    LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
                {
                    if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
                    {
                        tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                        if (impersonationContext != null)
                        {
                            CloseHandle(token);
                            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(token);
            if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero)
                CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate);
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Undoes the current impersonation.
        /// </summary>
        private void undoImpersonation()
        {
            impersonationContext.Undo();
        }


        private static void CopyFilesRecursively(string sourcePath, string targetPath)
        {
            try
            {
                foreach (string dirPath in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath));
                }

                //Copy all the files & Replaces any files with the same name
                foreach (string newPath in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
                {
                    File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(sourcePath, targetPath), true);
                }
                MessageBox.Show("File copied successfully");
            }catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            //Now Create all of the directories
            
        }

    
    }
    
}
```

Comment: The user needs permissions to the Share as well as the folder

Comment: Yes i have given access to the folder both source and destination for the user id

Comment: You need both Share and NTFS permissions, see eg https://www.lepide.com/blog/whats-the-difference-between-share-and-ntfs-permissions/